# phpBB automated email notifications to all members regarding all posts

Tags: php, forum, phpbb, phpbb3

While I search this one out on my own, may be some one could provide quick answer. Thank you so much in advance.

So i really enjoy google groups and how every member receives notification about all new things that happen in the group. All new topics, old topics, added replies and so on. But we need our own forum, so my group went with phpBB forum on our site.

I basically want my board to send out notifications to all members. So that members that are on the phone do not have to be present on the forum physically.

Any one faced this issue before, any quick solutions? Settings in phpBB that can address that right away. May be custom setting for groups?

==============================================================================

As I have found out, actually every user can subscribe to forums. Haven't been looking hard enough or just missed it. That produces desired effect for me. But so far I have no idea of a way to force that behavior for all users regardless of their actions. Which would be preferable for small board. But good news if this natively supported by phpBB i bet i can write some code to extend this feature.

Comment: individual emails for every post, or a digest-style daily update?

Comment: either way, individual preferably. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question on phpBB forums: thats what I got -> http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=2106567&p=12877384#p12877384

there is apparently mod that is available.

thank you all for help.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is somehow forcing every member to subscriber to every applicable forum/thread.  I would look to do this via a back-end query, not through anything phpBB provides.

After looking online at the phpBB schema, I propose the following query set to be run daily via a cron job:

```
insert into phpbb_forums_watch
select distinct f.forum_id, u.user_id, 0
from phpbb_forums f, phpbb_users u
where u.user_type = 0
      and not exists (select 1 from phpbb_forums_watch 
                  where forum_id = f.forum_id
                        and user_id = u.user_id);

insert into phpbb_topics_watch
select distinct t.topic_id, u.user_id, 0
from phpbb_topics t, phpbb_users u
where u.user_type = 0
      and not exists (select 1 from phpbb_topics_watch 
                  where topic_id = t.topic_id
                        and user_id = u.user_id);
```

Let me know what you think of this..

Comment: interesting, this might work for this purpose. thank you Fosco.